# React-Redux Search problem data from api. Action call unlimited

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, react-redux, redux-saga

When I search for any data Redux call action unlimited. It gives me the right details also and calls undefined unlimited time. How can I resolve this?

**Action**

```
export const SEARCH_PRO = (query) =>{
    return {
        type: SEARCH_PROS,
        query,
       
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export const productData = (state = { searchDatas: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
            case SEARCH_PROS:
                console.warn("PRODUCT_LIST condition ", action.searchProds)
                return {searchDatas:[action.searchProds]}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**Saga**

```
function* searchProducts(data) {
    let result = yield fetch(`products/searchpro?search=${data.query}`);
    result = yield result.json();
    console.warn("products action is called", result)
    console.warn("products action is ", data.query)
    yield put({type: SEARCH_PROS, searchProds:result.products.data})
}

export function* productSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(SEARCH_PROS, searchProducts)
}
```

**Search Components**

```
<input type="search" className="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search your Products" onChange={(event) => dispatch(SEARCH_PRO(event.target.value))} />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an infinite loop in your saga!

The problem is that you are using the same action type, `SEARCH_PROS`, for two different actions: the one where you pass the `query` to initiate the search *and* the one where you pass the `searchProds` that you fetched from the API.

Your `productSaga` will take every action with the type `SEARCH_PROS` -- including the one which is dispatched from inside your `searchProducts` function.

You must change the two actions to have different types.  A common pattern is to use `SEARCH_PROS_PENDING` and `SEARCH_PROS_FULFILLED`.

I also recommend using the [redux-toolkit `createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) instead of redux-saga for this task, as it's a lot easier to write and to understand.